# Label of both the figure and subfigures

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I use a composed figure that contains two subfigures implemented via `subfloat`s. Example code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \subfloat[Workload = 1,000]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{img/fib-1k-dyn.eps}
        \label{subfig:fib1k}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Workload = 20,000]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{img/fib-20k-dyn.eps}
        \label{subfig:fib20k}
    }

    \label{fig:fib}
    \caption{Fibonacci benchmark with fixed workload, dynamic scheduling}
\end{figure}
```

When I refer to the first subfigure via `\ref{subfig:fib1k}` the really pretty text is displayed such as `5.1a` or `5.1b` in the analogous reference.

However, sometimes I need to refer to the whole image, i.e. `\ref{fib}`. In that case I'd expect `5.1` (without the letter of course). Instead, unknown reference is presented `??`.

How can I refer to it properly? I use `pdflatex` and `\usepackage{subfig}` package.

Comment: Alway, *always*, place the label after the caption!

Comment: @Johannes_B oh, I see... if you provide this information as an answer, I'll be pleased to mark it as an correct answer. Thank you